# Resizing LRU-cache

Tags: node.js, lru

I am using [LRU-caching package](https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache) for caching string data. Based on current heap size of V8, I need to change the size of the cache, but this package doesn't provide such kind of interface.
I need to achieve this in optimal way(not copying the whole memory) or find package which provides such kind of functionality.

Comment: The documentation you pointed to in your question answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it does see: https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache/blob/master/lib/lru-cache.js#L41

which should allow you to simply do `cache.max = newMaxValue;`